# Installation issue with Ant 1.9.4

Tags: ant

I have got a problem with the Ant installation version 1.9.4...

I've downloaded the Ant `apache-ant-1.9.4-src.zip` from apache official website and extracted the zip to `C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4`

I've added the below in environment variable

```
ANT_HOME : C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
PATH : %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

When I ran the "ant" cmd from command prompt, I got the below issue

> C:>ant
>   ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.

`C:\>echo %ANT_HOME%`

`C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4`

Moreover, Bin folder is not found in downloaded .zip package.

Please anyone let me know, what i did wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You have downloaded the source of Apache Ant. You need to download the binary package. It should be something like `apache-ant-1.9.4.zip`.

The alternative is of course to compile the binary on your machine.